# How to limit users in the new Stakeholder access level to only see their own work items?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

I just finished updating our Team Foundation Server 2013 from Update 3 to Update 4. So now I have the new "Stakeholder" access level that replaces the old "Limited" access level. You can find more information about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668124.aspx).

While all this additional features that don't require a CAL are nice for some users, I liked the limited rights of the old "Limited" access level for other users. For example, our customers can now view and edit our internal bugs and tasks. I don't want that.

How do I limit a user so it once again only has access to his own work items?

Comment: This was one I didn't expect.. A lot of customers (including me!) wanted the Stakeholder license. I didn't expect someone wanted to go back to the limited view. Are your customers really editing 'your' bugs and tasks? Isn't transparency something your customers appreciate?

Comment: @WouterdeKort I didn't gave them the chance to really edit our internal bugs, but that they can is already a problem. Looking back, I had to reopen more than one of their bugs because they closed them as verified although we didn't fix them yet. Seeing our internal bugs would be fine, but the edit rights should really be limited to their own.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the out-of-the-box UI with Update 4 onwards. I would suggest that you create a simple interface that does only what you want and give your externals that.

Its about a days work to create a simple work item only view using the API.

Answer (score 0):

I've now got a workaround of some sort, although it isn't perfect, therefore I'll let this question open.

- I've created a new TFS project group for external users.
- I've denied access to all project areas from this group.
- I've created a new area just for external bugs and granted the group full access to it.
- I've set this new area as the team default so that external users don't have to change the area for each new bug.
- I've moved all existing bugs to this new area.

This solution has one big problem: You can only have one default area. Work item type rules for the area field don't work. Therefore we now have to be careful to always change the area for new internal bugs.

Comment: What about to use templates ?
In our organization we use prepared templates (Backlog, Bug) what fill some of textboxes in work item and area is one of them. You can still have default are set to one which you use for internal bugs and force stakeholders to use Templates to create their work items mapped to other area.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Add MrX to a Stakeholder licens
2. Goto Manage project Area-section and on root Area use Arrow to get to Security. Add user MrX and set Deny on all permissions
3. Create a subarea called "STAKEINPUT"
4. Goto that subarea and use Arrow to get to Security. User is then displayed with inherited permissions. Set allow on Edit work item and Read work item permission.

Now MrX can browse on all area levels. But MrX can only see and edit stories in the backlog corresponding to the subteam STAKEINPUT.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I described in my answer?