# AD VSTS: Having business users submit feature requests/bugs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We use Visual Studio Team Services backed by Azure AD and want any user in our AD to be able to submit a feature or bug. I know some products like Jira allow this either through their issue collector or via email. It seems with VSTS the user has to be a stakeholder in the project or else they would receive a 401 (I tested with one user in our AD). Has anyone found a good solution or extension that allows AD users (or users external to the project) to submit features requests/bugs to a VSTS project? Or do we have to create something utilizing VSTS's REST API?

Comment: Why is that a problem? Stakeholder licenses are free and unlimited.

Comment: our user base will be very wide and we wouldn't know who to add until they tried to login and receive the 401, which isn't a very nice experience for the user. We want a simple approach that has little intervention on our part. We would rather not go in and out of VSTS adding stakeholders for users who just care about getting their request in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must be added to your VSTS, then he can submit a feature or bug work item. Regarding personal access token (can call [Work item REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item)), it is created by the user in your VSTS too, it is not recommended, because of the security issue and you don’t know who submit the feature or bug, it’s hard to manage.

Comment: so there is no access level (similar to github) where any logged in user can navigate to a project, request a feature/submit a bug and only change their requests (In our case it would only be AD users)? If i made everyone stakeholders, I would not want some stakeholders to run a muck on the backlog since they can change a backlog item and task, which I don't know why they would change a task because it should be very specific/technical to the developer.

Comment: and I misspoke when I said "so there is no access level"...i meant to say "so there is no way"

Comment: @JayMichael No. I recommend that you can build a app through API to just submit feature/bug. If you just use a account (do not add these users to VSTS), then you can't identify the work items who created.

Comment: thanks, and I think i found a similar answer after looking through some user voices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244676/how-to-limit-users-in-the-new-stakeholder-access-level-to-only-see-their-own-wor